# Integrating $\sinh(x)\cosh(x)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

So I am very new to integration. I have to find the integral of $\sinh(x)\cosh(x)$

I have tried different ways:

> (i) let $u = \sinh(x)$, (ii) let $u= \cosh(x)$,  and (iii) using the
>   identity $\sinh(2x) = 2 \sinh(x)\cosh(x)$

However, all of these result in different answers. In particular the answers are:

> (i) $\frac{\sinh^2(x)}{2}+C$, (ii) $\frac{\cosh^2(x)}{2} +C$, and (iii)
>   $\frac{1}{4}\cosh(2x) +C$

Comment: The derivative of $\sinh x$ with respect to $x$ is $\cosh x$. The substitution $u=\sinh x$ is then the appropriate route to take.

Comment: so, do you mean that the other answers are incorrect?

Comment: Fun fact: $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$

Comment: @Aaron Well, not necessarily. The substitution $u=\cosh x$ would work as well, since the derivative of such is $\sinh x$. I would use either i or ii, it does not really matter.

Comment: Guys, his answers all differ by a constant. That is all there is to it.

Comment: *However, all of these result in different answers.* - No, they don't. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indefinite integral is defined only up to an additive constant.  So all your answers are correct!
You may verify this by differentiating your answer and you should get the original function back.

Note that $\cosh (2x) = 2\cosh^2(x)-1 = 2\sinh^2(x)+1$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, by definition, we have: $$\sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \cosh x = \frac{e^x  + e^{-x}}{2}$$
It is an easy exercise to check that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sinh x = \cosh x$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\cosh x = \sinh x$. So, making $u = \sinh x$, we have $\mathrm{d}u = \cosh x \ \mathrm{d}x$, and hence: $$\int \sinh x \cosh x \ \mathrm{d}x = \int u \ \mathrm{d}u = \frac{u^2}{2} + c= \frac{\sinh^2 x}{2} + c.$$